# Burninate the [naming-conventions] tag

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Short and sweet:

> Burninate the [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) tag

Maybe it's just a honey-pot for off-topic questions, but I can't see any reason for this tag to stick around, nor can I see any reason how any of these questions *wouldn't* be opinion-based.

A sampling:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695201/good-name-for-object-that-creates-and-updates-another-object
- [Foreign key naming conventions, ModuleID vs ModuleId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656424/foreign-key-naming-conventions-moduleid-vs-moduleid)
- [Name convention for properties that are another class with a similar name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570663/name-convention-for-properties-that-are-another-class-with-a-similar-name)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558741/model-concerns-plural-or-singular
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553137/what-do-i-name-a-function-that-might-not-change-the-input

Comment: Of note... since there *is* such a honeypot of opinion questions, one should endeavor to close/delete them while they are in one place.  Tossing the tag and type into the close review filter may help in getting the ones that are in the close review queue now handled promptly.

Comment: While naming conventions are never entirely objective, it seems they can be close to it, if they cite sources of high repute (such as documentation for the language in question), and can be valuable for creating readable code. Why the hate? Is there another StackExchange site where such questions would be more relevant than on StackOverflow?

Comment: @maurice CodeReview?

Comment: @Degustaf thanks, I hadn't heard about that site. In that case, maybe it would be best to make a note in the tag description saying that if the tag fits, the question should be directed toward CodeReview. I know the tag description for _networking_ is how I discovered ServerFault.

Comment: @Degustaf Existence of a site with overlapping topic does *not* automatically make such questions off-topic. For example, people can still ask questions about latex, emacs, vim or writing python code for blender on SO even though they can be asked on the relative sites. However it can be a good idea to mention the site on the tag description.

Comment: @Bakuriu I'm not saying that the questions are off topic.  I was only saying that these question would be on-topic for another SE site.

Comment: **Of interest:** See the Wikipedia article [Naming convention (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29). This article also includes a discussion of [Language-specific conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Language-specific_conventions).

Answer (score 12):

> nor can I see any reason how any of these questions wouldn't be opinion-based"

Maybe you are fortunate to have never encountered some of the really terribly naming conventions I've seen.

Sometimes yes.  Often times though people make arbitrary decisions about naming something, only to pay the price later because they didn't follow common naming conventions for their language/framework.

**There is solid rationale behind many naming conventions.**  They sometimes avoid ambiguity, avoid conflicts between language elements that often appear in the same context but have different semantics, improves the readability/intuitiveness of an API(e.g. in C# not naming your custom collection class with a plural name, but name variable/property instances plural).

For example, if you have a namespace which is also the name of a class in C#, this is perfectly fine from a compiler standpoint, but it causes you to have to often fully qualify where it would otherwise be unnecessary, and some IDE features and code analysis tools will completely choke on this scenario.

Sometimes questions revolve around naming conventions that help an API fit into the nomenclature of common patterns/practices.  For example, naming various language elements involved in a factory pattern.

**I agree that there are some scenarios where there is no guiding rationale**, and thus the answer is simply something along the lines of "It is an arbitrary choice, but you should follow(or agree upon) the conventions established by colleagues on your team."  I think the question is *probably* still legitimate.  Note such an answer is not an opinion.  It is a statement of the fact that there is no guiding rationale in this particular case.  It is only an opinion if the answerer actually suggests a particular naming convention without supporting rationale.

C# has a book, I won't plug the name, but it was written by members of the .NET Framework team.  It has a large part of it dedicated to naming conventions.  Some of it is arbitrary, simply establishing a convention, but most of it has very specific rationale for choices made, and there's lots of anecdotes of pitfalls of not following certain naming conventions.  Lots of lessons learned where they made a bad decisions naming something in a way that later made it very hard to use the API in some scenarios.

I think it is short sighted to automatically assume such a question can only have an opinion based answer.  I don't intend to sound adversarial.  **My point is that these questions should be evaluated on their own merits.**  I've seen a couple individuals going around and applying some action all over SO with very poor judgement regarding the actual question at hand, and using a meta post to justify their actions.

Additionally, I don't think all questions are appropriate for code review.  If the answer is "You should not have a class name nested in the hierarchy where a namespace has the same name." is very generalized naming convention, and doesn't apply to a particular code example.

Comment: An objective source from Microsoft on naming conventions for the .NET Framework: [Capitalization Conventions (.NET Framework 4.5)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: An objective source on naming conventions for Python: [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code - Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to develop my answer to a comment about the viability of these questions on another SE websites.

> Is there another StackExchange site where such questions would be more relevant than on StackOverflow? - @maurice

> CodeReview? - @Degustaf

I don't think CodeReview is appropriate because these questions are mostly theorical, about how to name things **before** writing code.

As far as I know, [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is the best place to ask these questions. There is already a [naming tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/naming/info) with 359 [questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=[naming]+is%3Aq) at this moment, **but** some popular questions were closed:

- [Why is naming a table's Primary Key column “Id” considered bad practice? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/114728/113871)
- [Should the variable be named Id or ID? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/186277/113871)

So, Programmers.SE doesn't seem to be an appropriate place for these questions.

Comment: Programmers.SE has had a [*long* history with naming questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6582/40980). What  you are missing out is seeing the deleted answers like `I'd use ID - because the dictionary doesn't mention anything as "Id".` and `I use _id. Yes, it's a matter of preference, but it's a strong preference. CamelCaseChafes.` The problem we have with such questions is that rarely generate good answers and all too often have become polls of "I like to use..." and generate really crap answers.

Comment: ... so we close them so they can't get any more answers from well meaning new users who don't understand the expectations of quality. Questions that aren't closed all too often get answers of similar quality as the worst ones in the question from new users... which then either get down voted or deleted.