# Tag listed, but not usable

Tags: support, tags

I just asked a question about naming conventions, and I looked for what tags were available, and I found that there was a [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) tag, but when I added it to the list of tags for the question, I was told that I need 1500 reputation to create a new tag.

I even cut-and pasted the tag just in case there was some typo I was somehow overlooking. Why is it viewed as a new tag when it's listed as a tag?

Comment: Hmm...should that tag even exist?  (More philosophical than technical here.)

Comment: Also, were you referring to your recent post here on Meta which...was removed and you attempted to ask a question about naming conventions?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth:  I'm more than willing to bet that the OP tried to use the main-site tag on Meta, which doesn't translate across.

Comment: @Makato Yes. Although your wording is odd, as it suggests that I attempted to ask a question about naming conventions after it was removed. I don't see how that question was off-topic for meta, and I don't understand why this question has been down-voted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

- Tags don't cross site boundaries.  A tag on the main site is not a tag on Meta.  You posed your question on Meta attempting to use the main site tag, and that doesn't work.
- Your question was *very* much off-topic for Meta (and the main site, too).  Here's the body of it for those who [can't see it as it is now deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356941/generic-list-naming-convention):

  > It seems to be a convention, if a generic list name is needed, to use "l". This looks a lot like "1" in many fonts. The first few times I saw this, I read it as, e.g., 1 = [a,b,c], which was rather confusing. Should effort be made to establish an alternative convention?

  That's going to do nothing but draw and garner *opinion*, and not *fact*, and as such, that sort of question is not on-topic here at Stack Overflow.

<s>I should thank you; we may have impetus to get [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) burninated.</s> ([Beaten to the punch and shot down years ago.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287291/1079354))

Comment: But the tag says "A tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and often subjective. If it is not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion." Why is there a tag for opinions, if opinions are off-topic? Also, here are some questions currently on Meta: "Shouldn't Answers with more Upvotes than the “Marked as Answer” answer be highlighted somehow?" "Don't show the Salary popup if it's not supported in your country" "Should [react-google-maps] be re-tagged as [google-maps-react]" Those look subjective to me.

Comment: @Acccumulation:  Yours was a *programming* opinion, not an opinion of how Stack Overflow is operating or running.  You didn't want to talk about the site; you wanted to talk about programming opinions.

Comment: "Yours was a programming opinion". No, it wasn't. I was asking about Stack Overflow posts. People write "l" in Stack Overflow posts. My personal opinion is they shouldn't write "l" in Stack Overflow posts. I asked whether Stack Overflow should have an official policy regarding writing "l" in Stack Overflow posts. Such a policy would affect how Stack Overflow operates. This is only tangentially related to what people write in their actual code.

Comment: @Acccumulation: You're going to want to show an example of this.  Every example that I've seen that's referred to code has been `code formatted`, eliminating any ambiguity.

Comment: @Acccumulation I guess your question was just unclear then because I also thought you were talking about a convention in a programming language, not a convention among Stack Overflow users. If you do see code that isn't formatted properly (including inline code) edit the post to fix it.