# Why is there a tag called naming-conventions if questions about naming conventions are closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted the question [What are the standard naming conventions for non-type template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70379336/what-are-the-standard-naming-conventions-for-non-type-template-parameters). It was almost immediately closed as opinion-based. I don't really understand how the question was opinion-based since I asked if there were any standard, **agreed-upon** naming conventions.

I know meta sites get a lot of "Why was my question closed"-questions and I'm not here to waste your time with another one. My question is only why there even is a [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) tag if almost all questions that use it seem to be negatively received. Most of them are closed as opinion-based and the ones that aren't seem to be just as opinion-based but not receiving enough traction to be found and closed.

Isn't [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) inherently opinion-based, since naming conventions most often don't affect how a program executes?

Comment: People make tags for off-topic questions all the time. The fact that the community hasn't gotten around to closing them all doesn't make them any less on-topic; and even if they are closed if the question is upvoted, or has answers that are (or accepted as the solution) it's unlikely they will ever get deleted; at least not by Roomba. The existence of a tag or another question on the topic does not mean a question is on topic now, or will be in the future.

Comment: There are no *standardized* naming conventions for C++ (unlike certain other languages), which makes your question inherently opinion-based. Unfortunately, that's only something one can know if they already know, but fortunately, there's no penalty for having a question closed.

Comment: Even the example question in the tag info is closed as a duplicate of a question that's closed as POB :)

Comment: It is, incidentally, worth noting that [the \[naming-conventions\] tag was previously suggested for removal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287291/burninate-the-naming-conventions-tag), but that did not garner enough community support to be done.

Comment: A naming convention question doesn't have to be "What naming convention should I use?" I can imagine a hypothetical question about enforcing or automating naming conventions with particular tools or code being on-topic.

Comment: In that situation, the naming-conventions tag wouldn't be necessary or helpful.